# Plotting series using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

```
category = df.category_name_column.value_counts()
```

I have the above series which returns the values:

```
CategoryA,100
CategoryB,200
```

I am trying to plot the top 5 category names in X - axis and values in y-axis

```
head = (category.head(5)) 
sns.barplot(x = head ,y=df.category_name_column.value_counts(), data=df)
```

It does not print the "names" of the categories in the X-axis, but the count. How to print the top 5 names in X and Values in Y?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can pass in the series' `index` & `values` to `x` & `y` respectively in `sns.barplot`. With that the plotting code becomes:

```
sns.barplot(head.index, head.values)
```

> I am trying to plot the top 5 category names in X

calling `category.head(5)` will return the first five values from the series `category`, which may be different than the *top 5* based on the number of times each category appears. If you want the 5 most frequent categories, it is necessary to sort the series first & then call `head(5)`. Like this:

```
category = df.category_name_column.value_counts()
head = category.sort_values(ascending=False).head(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Since the previous accepted solution is [deprecated in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64130332/seaborn-futurewarning-pass-the-following-variables-as-keyword-args-x-y). Another workaround could be as follows:**

1. Convert series to dataframe

```
category = df.category_name_column.value_counts()  
category_df = category.reset_index()
category_df.columns = ['categories', 'frequency']
```

2. Use barplot

```
ax = sns.barplot(x = 'categories', y = 'frequency', data = category_df)
```

Although this is not exactly plot of series, this is a workaround that's officially supported by seaborn.

For more barplot examples please refer here:

1. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html
2. https://stackabuse.com/seaborn-bar-plot-tutorial-and-examples/

Comment: Note that there's nothing deprecated about plotting a series in seaborn. The deprecation warning is only about whether `x` and `y` are implicit (deprecated) or explicit (supported), so the accepted answer is still fully supported as long as we specify `x` and `y` explicitly: `sns.barplot(x=head.index, y=head.values)`