# FutureWarning: Pass the following variables as keyword args: x, y

Tags: python, seaborn, typeerror, keyword-argument, positional-argument

I want to plot a seaborn regplot.
my code:

```
x=data['Healthy life expectancy']
y=data['max_dead']
sns.regplot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

However this gives me future warning error. How to fix this warning?

```
FutureWarning: Pass the following variables as keyword args: x, y. From version 0.12, the only valid 
positional argument will be 'data', and passing other arguments without an explicit keyword will 
result in an error or misinterpretation.
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Seaborn 0.12

- With `seaborn 0.12`, the `FutureWarning` from `seaborn 0.11` is now an `TypeError`.
- **Only `data` may be specified as the first positional argument for seaborn plots. All other arguments must use keywords (e.g. `x=` and `y=`).** This applies to all `seaborn` plotting functions.

  - `sns.*plot(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm")` or `sns.*plot(penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm")`
  - `sns.*plot(data=penguins.bill_length_mm)` or `sns.*plot(penguins.bill_length_mm)`
  - See [Overview of seaborn plotting functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html)
- Some potential errors for incorrect use of positional and keyword arguments with seaborn:

  - `TypeError: *plot() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 3 were given` occurs when no keywords are passed.

    - `sns.*plot(penguins, "bill_length_mm", "bill_depth_mm")`
  - `TypeError: *plot() got multiple values for argument 'data'` occurs when `data=` is used after passing `x` and `y` as positional arguments.

    - `sns.*plot("bill_length_mm", "bill_depth_mm", data=penguins)`
  - `TypeError: *plot() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given` occurs when positional arguments are passed for `x` and `y`, followed by a keyword argument other than `data`

    - `sns.*plot(penguins.bill_length_mm, penguins.bill_depth_mm, kind="reg")`
- See [TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23944657/7758804) for the general `python` explanation.
- [Positional argument vs keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9450656/7758804)

---

### Seaborn 0.11

- Technically, it's a warning, not an error, and can be ignored for now, as shown in the bottom section of this answer.
- I recommend doing as the warning says, specify the `x` and `y` parameters for [`seaborn.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html), **or any of the other [seaborn plot functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/api.html) with this warning.**
- `sns.regplot(x=x, y=y)`, where `x` and `y` are parameters for `regplot`, to which you are passing `x` and `y` variables.
- Beginning in version 0.12, passing any [positional arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument), except `data`, will result in an `error` or `misinterpretation`.

  - For those concerned with backward compatibility, write a script to fix existing code, or don't update to 0.12 (once available).
- `x` and `y` are used as the data variable names because that is what is used in the OP. Data can be assigned to any variable name (e.g. `a` and `b`).
- This also applies to `FutureWarning: Pass the following variable as a keyword arg: x`, which can be generated by plots only requiring `x` or `y`, such as:

  - `sns.countplot(penguins['sex'])`, but should be `sns.countplot(x=penguins['sex'])` or `sns.countplot(y=penguins['sex'])`

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')

x = penguins.culmen_depth_mm  # or bill_depth_mm
y = penguins.culmen_length_mm  # or bill_length_mm

# plot without specifying the x, y parameters
sns.regplot(x, y)
```

[image]

```py
# plot with specifying the x, y parameters
sns.regplot(x=x, y=y)

# or use
sns.regplot(data=penguins, x='bill_depth_mm', y='bill_length_mm')
```

[image]

#### Ignore the warnings

- I do not advise using this option.
- Once seaborn v0.12 is available, this option will not be viable.
- From version 0.12, the only valid positional argument will be `data`, and passing other arguments without an explicit keyword will result in an error or misinterpretation.

```py
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action="ignore", category=FutureWarning)

# plot without specifying the x, y parameters
sns.regplot(x, y)
```

[image]